# Create Auto Sequence text and number in oracle 11g

Tags: sql, oracle

How I do create column ID with value `JASG1`?
I am only find example like this :

```
select 'JASG'||to_char(mtj_id_seq.nextval) from talend_job
```

Comment: Is the text `JASG` always the same for every row?  If so, then what you wrote above is one way to do this.  If the letters change too, then give us the logic behind the sequence.

Comment: yes JASG will continue and sequence like this :
JASG1
JASG2
JASG3
JASG4
@TimBiegeleisen

Comment: If the column should contain the prefix JASG for each and every row, then why do you want to store it in the first place? Just store the number and add the prefix when displaying it. Or create a view, or a virtual column that concatenates both

Answer (score 0):

Although what you wrote probably works (if there's a sequence named `MTJ_ID_SEQ`, you have a privilege to select from it; the same goes for the `TALEND_JOB` table), I'd say that it isn't what you should use.

Here's why: I'll create a table and a sequence. Table will be pre-populated with some IDs (just to put something in there).

```
SQL> create sequence mtj_id_seq;

Sequence created.

SQL> create table talend_job as
  2    select rownum id from dept;

Table created.

SQL> select * from talend_job;

        ID
----------
         1
         2
         3
         4
```

OK; 4 rows so far. Now, run your `SELECT`:

```
SQL> select 'JASG'||to_char(mtj_id_seq.nextval) from talend_job;

'JASG'||TO_CHAR(MTJ_ID_SEQ.NEXTVAL)
--------------------------------------------
JASG1
JASG2
JASG3
JASG4

SQL> select 'JASG'||to_char(mtj_id_seq.nextval) from talend_job;

'JASG'||TO_CHAR(MTJ_ID_SEQ.NEXTVAL)
--------------------------------------------
JASG5
JASG6
JASG7
JASG8

SQL>
```

See? You didn't get only 1 `JASGx` value, but as many as number of rows in the `TALEND_JOB` table. If there was a million rows, you'd get a million `JASGx` rows as well.

Therefore, *maybe* you meant to use `DUAL` table instead? E.g.

```
SQL> select 'JASG'||to_char(mtj_id_seq.nextval) from dual;

'JASG'||TO_CHAR(MTJ_ID_SEQ.NEXTVAL)
--------------------------------------------
JASG9

SQL> select 'JASG'||to_char(mtj_id_seq.nextval) from dual;

'JASG'||TO_CHAR(MTJ_ID_SEQ.NEXTVAL)
--------------------------------------------
JASG10

SQL>
```

See? Only one value.

Also, notice that sequences will provide unique values, but you can't rely on them being gapless.

---

As you mentioned "how to create column ID" - one option is to use a trigger. Here's an example:

```
SQL> create table talend_job (id varchar2(20), name varchar2(20)

Table created.

SQL> create or replace trigger trg_bi_tj
  2    before insert on talend_job
  3    for each row
  4  begin
  5    :new.id := 'JASG' || mtj_id_seq.nextval;
  6  end;
  7  /

Trigger created.
```

Let's insert some names; IDs should be auto-populated by the trigger:

```
SQL> insert into talend_job (name) values ('littlefoot');

1 row created.

SQL> insert into talend_job (name) values ('Ishak');

1 row created.

SQL> select * From talend_job;

ID                   NAME
-------------------- --------------------
JASG11               littlefoot
JASG12               Ishak

SQL>
```

OK then; now you have some more info - read and think about it.

By the way, what is the "compiler-errors" tag used for? Did you write any code and it failed? Perhaps you'd want to share it with us.

Comment: ok i'm understand but when i'm create trigger ,just appear dialog box  'Enter binds' ,whether it must be filled or not? @Littlefoot

Comment: i found error like this when i'm create trigger :
1.Error(2,3): PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'NEW.ID'
2.Error(2,11): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ":" when expecting one of the following:     := . ( @ % ; indicator The symbol ":= was inserted before ":" to continue. 
3.Error(3,1): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "END" when expecting one of the following:     . ( * @ % & = - + ; < / > at in is mod remainder not rem    <an exponent (**)> <> or != or ~= >= <= <> and or like like2    like4 likec between || member submultiset The symbol ";" was substituted for "END" to continue.@Littlefoot

Comment: It is impossible to debug code you can't see. Please, edit your initial message (question) and post code you wrote.

Comment: sory man yesterday I typed wrong question..I tried to create trigger and now its work..thank you @Littlefoot